# I want to calculate the salary of Employee

Tags: asp.net

```
double Basicsalary = Double.Parse(txtBasicSalary.Text);
double Salary = Convert.ToDouble (txtSalary.Text);
double SA = Basicsalary * 0.11;
double SO = Basicsalary * 0.005;
double SASO = SA + SO;
txtTotalSalary.Text = (Convert.ToDouble (SASO)).ToString();
```

It Doesn't works with me what's the Solution for this issues

Comment: thefirrstSolution.isThat()youneedToknow().howto.FormatyourCode().

Comment: it shows me there's error in double BasicSalary

Comment: how to format it  is this code true, i try by my self but it doesn't works and try others it also doesn't works. i need code for that ?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think there mistake the parentheses

txtTotalSalary.Text = (Convert.ToDouble(SASO).ToString());

Comment: how can i handle this problem, no the issues with double Basicsalary only

Answer (score 0):

`SASO` is already declared as `double` and so no point in converting to `double` again. You can just assign it to textbox by calling `Tostring()` on it like

```
txtTotalSalary.Text = SASO.ToString();
```

Comment: even when I do this it show me there's error like this "Input string was not in a correct format.   double Basicsalary =Convert.ToDouble(txtBasicSalary.Text);

Comment: That's because `txtBasicSalary.Text` doesn't contain double type value.

Comment: Make sure you enter a double type value in text box. That will solve the issue.